# i get an interpolation error when calling terraform and and I don't know how to get rid of it

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

on main.tf line 39, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_first_task":
39:   execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `"${`and `}"` parts from the expression. That is the deprecated interpolation syntax that you are getting warned on. Just leave only the variable name. It will resolve properly and you will not get that warning.

Comment: When I remove the ${ and } I get this:                                                                                                                                                                                           
Error: "execution_role_arn" (aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix

  on main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_first_task":
  16: resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "my_first_task" {

Comment: My bad. You were completely right. I iterated with the above suggestion and took care of it. Thanks!

Comment: You bet! Kindly accept answer if you found it solved your question.

Comment: I bumped it up 1. Hope that helps.